# Don't snap windows to edge when moving between monitors

Tags: linux-mint, window-manager, xfce

I am running Linux-mint 13 with XFCE. When I drag a window to the side of the screen it snaps to the side and fills up that vertical half of the screen.

This is great, but I have two graphics cards so I can have two monitors. I can't drag a window from one monitor to the other because it snaps to the side of the the first screen. I have to open applications on the 2nd screen, and then they are stuck there.

I assume I need to disable this feature (even though I quite like it). I can't find any option for it anywhere. How do I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it, posted too soon it seems!

I had to enable Xinerama (in the nvidia-settings app) to have the two displays work together.

Before I had my desktop icons on both screens so I should have guessed they weren't working as one continuous desktop them. Now they are only on the left screen.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the feature by unchecking "Automatically tile windows when moving toward the screen edge" under the Accessibility tab in Window Manager Tweaks (xfwm4-tweaks-settings).